# Are null terminators good for parsing binary files

Tags: c, file, null, binary

I'm trying to work on a save game system and I'm stuck on trying to figure out the best way to use c-strings. I know I could use an int to mark the number of characters but I'm wondering if using a null terminator is a good idea. (Especially since currently I'm having issues trying to find the null terminator in the loading end)

TL;DR Question: Is using a null terminator in binary files best practice for strings, and if not, what do you recommend instead.

Also, if you could tell me how to find a null terminator in the middle of my memory buffer (a C string) that would be great, but I know technically it's a different question.

Comment: It's not much better or worse than any other option.

Comment: How would you tell the *nul-byte* (e.g. `0`) at the end of a string apart from every other *nul-byte* in your binary file? (like the one in `short a = 10;`)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a NULL terminator to mark the ends of strings in a binary file is that binary files may contain NULL characters. If you know that you'll never be storing NULL characters in the file, except to mark the end of a string, you'll be fine.

If it is possible that you will have NULL characters in the file, then you could predefine the length of strings, but then you'd need to know beforehand the maximum length of the strings that you'll be storing. For example, you could say that ever string must take up 128 characters having the unused characters be filled with NULLs.

If none of those solutions work in this situation, you can always prefix every string with its length.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using SQLite for file format. It is easier to handle.

And you can insert blobs on it.

Think about when you need to update the file format. Using SQLite it is a piece of cake. Just add a new column to the table or use UPDATE...

Check: https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html

Comment: Is SQLlite comparable in speed and size to C Binary Files (I'm not even using fstreams as I know they're harsher on CPU). Also, won't I need to serialize data for networking eventually? I've never done networking but I figured this is two birds with one stone.

Comment: There is more processing than simply reading the file, but the advantages for general use are big. Did you check the page? For binary serialization in C check [binn](https://github.com/liteserver/binn)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to provide specifications for your binary file.  In your case, you would then need to figure out how to escape the null terminator if you actually want it counted as data.  Is that worth the pain to check each character?  It is easier to do as you mentioned by having a predefined length or a length read in from the file.  If the field you are reading is actually an array of strings with null terminators, perhaps you should specify the length of the total array, and deal with the `split` of the strings once it is read into variables.

Comment: Thanks! My plan was something similar to JSON, but simpler. ie: npc_houndeye{name:bob,hp:45}. I just need to figure out the fastest, smallest way to write it, but I know I need field names for backwards compatibility between versions. The reason I didn't want ints is it would a)take up space and B) be confusing. May be faster though.

Comment: No need to optimize unless you see the loading/saving is too slow

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm optimizing because I'm working on dozens of different systems, all of which take up memory and speed. It's better to tackle overhead as much as I can in each compartment than to freak out when it's slow later.

Comment: Is parsing JSON so slow? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". The game saving/loading only occurs at some point during the gameplay process, and often when the user paused playing, so a quarter second faster file load they won't noticed. What's more important is the loading of the game scene which often takes much longer and irritates the players